Is there any better way to find whether lighting component is loaded or not, from a diifferent (not related) LWC present on the same screen(in flow)
My use case is that:

I have LWC component embedded in a screen flow -> 'validation' LWC. This flow is triggered as action of quick action on record detail page. This flow basically submits the record.
Another aura component 'form.cmp' is present on the same detail page which is under one of the tabs. This component is basically a form and contains some UI validations like character limit and required fields.
Flow LWC 'Validation' should communicate with this aura component and validates that user does not have any pending errors on same screen (like if user has entered invalid dates/numbers). If there are some errors, need to show them in screen flow and inform user that he/she can not submit the record.
If user has not opened the tab, then this flow simply skips the validation.

Sample UI >>


I am thinking to do this communication via Lightning Message Service. Using LMS, I will communicate from LWC to aura ( a request to send me validation result) and then from aura component to LWC ( response containing validation result).
However there is possibility that aura component I want to do the communication with may not be opened by user and hence I will not get any communication back from the aura. This is my concern and main issue.
I may wait for some random time and then proceed thinking that I have not received any response (using setInterval).Do not think this as a better way though.
My objective here is to know if there is any better way to check whether a particular component has loaded or not (i.e. user has clicked the tab and loaded the component under it, so I can communicate with it)

One of the suggestion that I got is to use sessionStorage/localStorage to add component name as one of the value once component is loaded. However since this development is actually for a managed package, I am not so sure about the use of sessionStorage(although I agree I am not storing any sensitive data but mostly not sure whether this will be flagged by Salesforce Security team and then eventually I have to remove it/change my approach)
Is there any better way in LWC to identify if particular aura/LWC lightning component is loaded or not in the DOM?
I have seen Salesforce has something known as "isConnected" but looks like it only checks the current component is loaded or not? There is no proper documentation or mention that it checks for other outside components.

To ensure that components are aware of each other, they should each send an initial message to establish the relationship. This can be through MessageChannel, LMS, or pubsub, whatever your preference. TheForm and TheValidation components would each send an initial handshake on connectedCallback (LWC)/valueInit (Aura). Each side should send one handshake when they initialize, and record when they have received the corresponding handshake in return. Once this happens, you know that you can communicate between the two components. At this point, TheValidation knows whether or not it should expect a response, etc.

Thanks for the immediate response @sfdcfox , really appreciate it. Yes got it. Initial handshake is necessary & can help in further communication. However even for handshake both components should send each other a message but here, there is possibility that aura component TheForm may not be opened/loaded by user. The lwc comp "TheValidation" in this case should not wait till it receives a message, instead if its not loaded/opened then it can skip that validation and move ahead. So for the component "TheValidation" needs to check if TheForm comp is there or not. Is there any way to do that?

@prasad_sawant_75 The initial handshake is the method to do this. If TheValidation has received a message from TheForm, then it has been loaded, otherwise it has not. You cannot just query the DOM arbitrarily to find the component.

okay so initial handshake is the only way here. Agree with the query part, thanks. I will go for handshake approach then and wait for max X amount of time or until I receive the message. If I don't get reply within time I will assume component is not loaded & will proceed.(Trying to avoid this time polling loop so looking for better way for this) I will also explore your static storage space idea you shared in this post. This idea looks really interesting & promising. Thanks @sfdcfox.

mostly it will not be time polling here, it will be just one time check after X seconds to know if I have received any handshake response or not.

@prasad_sawant_75 Here's the thing... lightning tabs load their content lazily. So it may be a second, a minute, or never, depending on if the user clicks on the tab. All you need to know is if you received the message or not.

Yeah @sfdcfox, that's the concern I had. I need to skip validation in the screen flow if component is not there but only way to know that is If I receive handshake from it and I will never receive it, if user never clicked, or as you said if salesforce takes more time which is not in our hand anyway.  Maybe if there is common space shared by these components or static storage which I can take help of then. Simply adding component name there once its loaded (from connectedCallback/init) and accessing it from another component to know if its loaded. Will explore this part.

@prasad_sawant_75 Again, if you design it correctly, if TheValidation receives a handshake, it knows the TheForm is loaded, and if not, it knows it is not loaded. That is the purpose of the handshake. However, alternatively, you can use a TheService component to communicate the presence of the component. In your service component, export a variable that you can then set the value for. e.g. const settings = {}; export default settings;, and then: import settings from 'c/service'; ... settings.theFormLoaded = true ... if(settings.theFormLoaded) ...

Okay thanks @sfdcfox I think I got the second approach you said. There's something about the handshake process which I am not able to get it correctly I feel then, but that's me. Really sorry if I irritated you by asking same thing again and again. I will explore "the proper design of handshake" part again. For now second approach will do the job for me. Thank you once more for all your help & quick replies.

@prasad_sawant_75 Hey, no problem. I'll see if I can't update this answer tomorrow with an example.

That would be super super helpful, thank you so much!!!

@prasad_sawant_75 Here you go. You can clone this repo and deploy into any org that won't conflict with the names. Create a Lightning Tab to see it in action. It's uncommented, but should be fairly self-explanatory, I think.

Hey @sfdcfox thank you so much for this. Just one more help, I am not able to access this link. Its saying Page not found. Can you please confirm, the link is correct?

@prasad_sawant_75 Looks like I made a mistake? Try this link.

This is working. Thank You!!
